# Eclipse and Android development - a few noob questions

Tags: java, android, eclipse, console

I've tested deployment to Android Market already as a test, seems like everything is hooked up fine - but now getting a little deeper into java and need to figure out how to use the Eclipse IDE.

1. I'm having exceptions, but where can see the exception message?.. it's not showing up in my consoles , not even the java stack trace console while in debug mode?

   URLConnection uconn = null;
   try {
   uconn = u.openConnection();
   catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   x = x + e.toString();
   }
2. Where does this output, not seeing it in any of the consoles. How can I output to console?

   System.out.println("-----------------hello");
3. I can open up the view variable windows, but see no variables there, how do I add them into that so I can see their values, are they only they only visible if I add a line breakpoint? btw, what's the function key to step to next breakpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Android exceptions are usually
   visible at *LogCat* view, it is
   available at *DDMS* perspective or you
   can add it through menu *Window ->
   Show View -> Other.. -> Android*
2. You'd better use log feature if you need to output something for debugging
   `Log.i("some tag", "message");` The log message is then visible at the *LogCat* view.
3. You need to stop at a breakpoint to see current value of variable, otherwise that makes not sense. Function keys from *F5* till *F8* are used to manipulate the flow. Usually *F8* will bring you to the next breakpoint.